# Python for the absolute beginner 3rd edition Chapter 9 example 3 doesn't seem to work

Tags: python-3.x

So I have been going through the book and have been retyping the code exactly from the book into Notepad++ and then running in the command line. There's a couple of things which are bugging me. For one the code does not seem to work and I am copying it pretty much exactly as it says in the book.

```
# example 3
# card game 2.0
# Aims: Learn about: Inheritance, Base Class, Derived Class

class Card(object):

    """ A playing card. """
    RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
    SUITS = ["c", "d", "h", "s"]

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.rank + self.suit
        return rep

class Hand(object):

    """ A hand of playing cards. """

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __str__(self): 
        if self.cards:
            rep = ""
            for card in self.cards:
                rep += str(card) + "\t"
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
        return rep

    def clear(self): 
        self.cards = []

    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def give(self, card, other_hand):
        self.cards.remove(card)
        other_hand.add(card)

class Deck(Hand):
    """ A Deck of Playing Cards"""
    def populate():
        for suit in Card.SUITS: 
            for rank in Card.RANKS:
                self.add(Card(rank, suit)

    def shuffle(self):
        import random
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, hands, per_hand = 1):
        for rounds in range(per_hand):
            for hand in hands:
                if self.cards:
                    top_card = self.cards[0]
                    self.give(top_card, hand)
                else:
                    print("Can't continue deal. Out of cards!")

# main
deck1 = Deck()

print("Created a new deck.")
print("Deck:")
print(deck1)

deck1.populate

print("\nPopulated the deck.")
print("Deck:")
print(deck1)
```

I have created 3 classes Card, Hand and Deck. In the main section of the programme when I try to call the method 'populate' the method should call and run through the list of class atrributes from the Card class and provide me with a list of possible cards when i print deck1, however I am always getting  back why is this the case?

My second question is that sometimes I seem to be getting a syntax error for 'def shuffle(self)' and I see no problem with this method.

Comment: _"however I am always getting back why is this the case?"_ Sorry, I don't understand what this sentence means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem

> In the main section of the programme when I try to call the method 'populate' the method should call and run through the list of class atrributes from the Card class and provide me with a list of possible cards when i print deck1, however I am always getting back why is this the case?

You aren't *calling* populate, `deck1.populate` won't call it, use `deck1.populate()` instead.

And you haven't defined it correctly either, it should take a parameter:

```
# ...
def populate(self):
    # ...
```

As for your second problem

> My second question is that sometimes I seem to be getting a syntax error for 'def shuffle(self)' and I see no problem with this method.

You have

```
            # ...
            self.add(Card(rank, suit) # <-- Syntax error

def shuffle(self):
```

The line with `self.add` is missing a closing parentheses

Answer (score 0):

`deck1.populate` is a function, so you need call it in this  way:
`deck1.populate()`